# How to make interactive charts together with R language

Tags: r, charts, interactive

I'm helping my friend make a website. He previously used R language to generate statistical charts. Now he want to generate some dynamic chart so that when users move mouse over certain part of the chart there will be some description/complementary information pops up for them to read. What kind of technology/tools/packages I can use for this purpose?

PS: I've explored some possible ways, yet none of them fits my needs. I've tried rggobi + ggobi. They can't coz they are not for web applications. iPlot can't do it coz it generates histogram only. I've thought about asking R produces some intermediate date which I can pass to some JavaScript packages like HighCharts. Yet, apparently R is much powerful than JS. R can generates some advanced type of charts which JS just can't do.

Comment: In what way 'interactive'? When viewed from another R session, or when viewed from a browser? (e.g. Rshiny)

Answer (score 4):

You should use R to generate the data and then export it in a format that a javascript framework for graphs can understand. 
This way you could benefit from the advanced statistical analysis provided by R and the presentation layer of javascript.

Lots of solutions exist for this problem, but i've heard lots of good things about [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and its [chart plugin](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), which you may want to investigate

Comment: I quite like protovis for web charting. R can generate JSON data that it can read in, using the rjson package.

Comment: @spacedman: RJSONIO is faster than rjson, since it's it mostly C code rather than R.

Comment: See also rwebvis by Shane (where is he these days?) for an interface to protovis and googleVis for an interface to the Google Visualization API.

Comment: @Spacedman & @Richie Cotton: obviously you've got more experience with R, you perhaps should add an answer; i think it would be interesting to have your first-hand experience for this question :) From what i see rwebvis and googlevis are very interesting in terms of integrating R and dynamic charts. And protovis (now obsolete, follow D3.js instead) is really nice!

Answer (score 2):

The playwith package offers facilities to manipulate rgl graphics. A couple of links:

http://code.google.com/p/playwith/w/list

http://www.r-bloggers.com/playing-with-the-%E2%80%98playwith%E2%80%99-package/

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sendplot package or the RSVGTipsDevice package.